# std::swap for non copiable but movable struct

Tags: c++, c++11, move, swap

According to [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/) `std::swap` is equivalent to

```
T c(std::move(a)); a=std::move(b); b=std::move(c);
```

This should allow to swap two non copiable but movable object. Therefore I don't understand why

```
#include<utility>

struct Foo {
  Foo() = delete;
  Foo(int) {};
  Foo(Foo &) = delete;
  Foo(Foo &&) {};
  ~Foo() {};
};

int main() {
  Foo a(1),b(2);
  std::swap(a,b);
}
```

is refused by the compiler with

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:59:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/utility:70,
                 from swap.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/move.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = Foo]’:
swap.cpp:13:16:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/move.h:176:11: error: use of deleted function ‘Foo& Foo::operator=(const Foo&)’
       __a = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__b);
           ^
swap.cpp:3:8: note: ‘Foo& Foo::operator=(const Foo&)’ is implicitly declared as deleted because ‘Foo’ declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
 struct Foo {
        ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:59:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/utility:70,
                 from swap.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/move.h:177:11: error: use of deleted function ‘Foo& Foo::operator=(const Foo&)’
       __b = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__tmp);
```

**note:** this is with GCC 4.8 and 4.9 but clang complain as well.

Comment: By declaring `Foo(Foo &)` as `=delete`, the copy assignment operator is also `=delete`, therefore, `a=std::move(b);` will cause an error.

Comment: That's on purpose. I don't want my class to be copied.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You declared a *move constructor*. However, you need a *move assignment operator* for `std::swap`. You should add the following two operators:

```
auto operator=(const Foo& rhs) & -> Foo& = delete;
auto operator=(Foo&& rhs) & noexcept -> Foo&
{
    // ...
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: +1, but there's no need to add the copy assignment op - when a class has a move assignment op, the copy one is defined as deleted if not user-provided. Also, it might be a good idea to make the move  operations non-throwing.

Comment: Didn't you forgot about some double && somewhere. These both look me as normal assignment operator ?

Comment: Ok ! I understand now. I though that move assignment was automatically generated from move constructor.

Comment: @hivert: If you think about it, that would be impossible. When you are assigning, the destination object might be managing some resource that will need to be cleaned up before it acquires the resource from the moved-from object. The move-constuctor cannot handle that (and need not)